# how can i set local key and foreign key in laravel eloquent-has-many-deep package

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the eloquent-has-many-deep package and I want to use the following link:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep#manytomany--manytomany

but i can't understand how to set local key and foreign key on this example.
please help me

Comment: Please follow the naming conventions. For the users' table, make `id` the primary key. `role_user` should have `id|role_id|user_id`, and the `permission_role` table should have `id|permission_id|role_id`. Same way, `roles` table should be having `id|name`, `permissions` table should have `id|name`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the same example from the package:

`User` → many to many → `Role` → many to many → `Permission`

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeep('App\Permission', ['role_user', 'App\Role', 'permission_role']);
    }
}
```

`role_user` and `permission_role` are pivot tables that are defined according to Laravel conventions (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Here `role_user` table would have an `user_id` field and a `role_id` field which are foreign keys `users` table and `roles` table respectively.

Therefore, the `role_user` table migration might look something like this (Laravel 7+):

```php
Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
});
```

`permission_role` table would follow a similar structure.